# Validation Design Pattern in PHP's Laravel (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, laravel, design-patterns

I have serious problem with choosing validation design pattern form my mid-large level project. I know two that they are quite nice, but I don't feel about which to choose:

#### 1 Validation inside model.

In L4.2 there was a bundle named: Ardent. He has few nice solutions. One of then was validation handle on before saving event. It was wery helpful especially for smaller project. Minus was that that validation logic was kept directly in model.

#### 2 Validation from service,

Another good practice that I know i validation from service. It means that we create servic for models that is responsible for write acions (mainly also for some of the reads). We can mange here validating on before any save (create, update etc.). In my opinion is better then my first propositon. The minus is - we have to remeber to put all model's input data through the service. Otherwise we won't get validation and other things directly from service.

Which of these two? Or maybe someone have something better, more clever? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'm in favor of #2 for the following reasons:

- Models tend to get bloated. Using modules with well-designed purposes helps with refactoring and code organization/management.
- Isolated validation modules are easier to test and debug in most cases.
- Validations in the model leaks abstractions from the model to the view and vice-versa.
- Less management of state. In the case of Rails, validations are handled by storing validation errors in a specific `errors` object. The operation is rather opaque and can be confusing and error-prone, especially when updating nested records.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion, you said you had a mid-large project, that's why I think you need:

- Data Repository - only for storing and retrieving raw data. As little logic goes here as possible.
- Business Model - all the smarts goes here, including validation.
- Service (i.e. client access) - a very thin piece, just enough to provide a connection to the client.

As your project grows this will help you organize your code, and in case you need various repositories (probably because of your projects size).